# Is this proper usage of the world 'proverbial'

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Daniel spots the contradiction almost immediately, recalling the moment when Sam had befriended Bobby with his story of the proverbial girlfriend he once called Janice—not Maggie."

I'm almost certain that the word 'proverbial' does not fit in this context as the word 'girlfriend'does not refer to a proverb of any sort, but I just want to confirm with you guys. My English is still not great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct. For something to be *proverbial* it must be an allusion or reference to a (well-known) proverb. I don't know any proverbs about *Janice the girlfriend*.

Comment: In common (informal) usage (in the  US), "proverbial" may be used to refer to something fictitious -- does not have to refer to a proverb.  However, it should generally be a reference to a "generic" fiction, rather than a specific one.

Comment: Just pulling an example out of the air, one might speak of "the proverbial traveling salesman" when discussing matters that resembled scenarios in the old traveling salesman stories.

Comment: In other words, I'm still wrong, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe even: "... the apocryphal girlfriend ..."

> **apocryphal**.  (of a story or statement) of doubtful authenticity

Comment: Yes!! This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to indicate that the story was made up, rather than being a true account, it would be better put as "his fictitious story of the girlfriend..." If the intent is that his story was true, but had been repeated so many times as to become familiar (to other friends who had heard it), it would be better put as "his oft-repeated story of the girlfriend..."